# Minimum Dependencies for Azure Mobile App

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-api-apps, azure-mobile-services

The new "[Azure Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop/)" resource (which supersedes "Azure Mobile Services") is very cool.  However, the sample code provided through the Azure portal (or found elsewhere online) assumes a maximum dependency tree, including a dependency on Entity Framework.  I would like to have minimal dependencies, but it is very difficult to recognize which dependencies I can "safely" remove.

The obvious answer is to remove dependencies that offer features I don't need - but the problem is that it is unclear what features are being offered by which dependencies.  Still, in a sense, this is only a third of the problem.

I know that I want to experiment with push notifications, authentication (e.g. OAuth) and Dapper hitting an Azure SQL Database for storage.  But...

I might choose to re-prioritize my research if only I could access a catalog of (all?) other features, allowing me to **discover features previously unknown to me**.  To give a "storage equivalent" example of what I mean, consider this [Azure storage options infographic](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/data-storage-options).  A picture worth a thousand words! Awesome!

The closest thing I've found to a "list of features" for an Azure Mobile App, is in this list of ["SDK Extensions" in a GitHub repo "readme" file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk.md).  Perhaps this list is close to being a solution for this next third of the problem I'm experiencing.

The final third of the problem is...history.  Microsoft is moving fast, with new features rapidly surfacing to replace older ones.  Sometimes I will get stuck reading several articles (not necessarily created by Microsoft) explaining how to use feature 'X', only to discover that feature 'X' has actually been superseded by feature 'Y' (doh!).  This final observation leads to the overall solution...

To tie it all together, I would love to have an (1) outline of Azure Mobile App features by category with a brief description, much like that infographic referenced earlier with (2) a reference to the key NuGet (or NPM) packages related to that feature and (3) an indication of the status of the feature (e.g. "active" / "superseded").  Yes, to my way of thinking it is more helpful to allow a deprecated feature to remain "on the list" with a "deprecated" flag (and a pointer to what tech or features replaced it!), rather than removing it from the list entirely.

Does anyone have material (or links, etc) that somewhat approximates this "outline" overview?  It would be the perfect guidance I need to find the features I want, with the minimum number of dependencies.

For reference sake...

The sample code that can be downloaded from an Azure account for a Mobile App has the following package dependencies:

### Mobile Api "packages.config"

```
<package id="AutoMapper" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.CrossDomain" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Home" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Quickstart" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables" version="0.2.575" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.205111437" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

### Azure API App "packages.config"

Contrast the above packages.config, with the new preview "[Azure API App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/)" resource type - which has the following packages.config:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.AppService.ApiApps.Service" version="0.9.16" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
<package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net46" />
```

This is delightfully lean.  I would like to slim-down to something close to this using the "super-cool-overview-outline" I described earlier.  Anyone have something like this? :}

Incidentally, if such an outline did exist - it could include a column which clarifies which features are currently available or not available in an Azure API App.  Woot!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could elaborate on which features you want and which you'd like to remove. That list is the min-set for Mobile Apps all up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you included the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Quickstart package, you did get a full set. If you wish to see the dependency graph visually, please see the [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk) where this package was introduced.

The only required package is Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server, which will bring in some basic dependencies

.Tables gives the TableController if you wish to use that.

.Entity depends on .Tables and EF, allowing integration between them (.Entity is the only package requiring EF).

.Notifications is required for push notifications

.CrossDomain is just for legacy web browsers

.Home provides a landing page for the root of the application

You can pick and choose any combination of these, as long as you have the Server package.

Comment: The blog post link you provided gives a 404.  Hopefully my slight edit of your answer is correct.